# Kendo chart - data from series at tooltip

Tags: jquery, kendo-chart

I create chart and I have problem with connect series data with tooltip.
I created array, like below which i fill data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < ChartData.SeriesList.length; i++) {
            Series.push({
                data: ChartData.SeriesList[i].Values,
                name: ChartData.SeriesList[i].SeriesName,
                time: ChartData.SeriesList[i].ExactDate
            });
        }
```

then I create kendo chart

```
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
            title: {
                text: "Sprzedaż"
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            chartArea: {
                background: ""
            },
            seriesDefaults: {
                type: "line",
                style: "smooth"
            },
            dataSource: {
                data: Series
            },

            series: Series,
            valueAxis: {
                labels: {
                    format: "{0}"
                },
                line: {
                    visible: false
                },
                axisCrossingValue: -10
            },
            categoryAxis: {
                categories: tab.length > 0 ? tab : ChartData.AxisValue,
                majorGridLines: {
                    visible: false
                },
                labels: {
                    rotation: "auto"
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}",
                template: "#= series.name #: #= dataItem #"
            }
        });
    }
```

And now I would like to print **Series.time** value at tooltip, but when I wrote this:

```
tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                format: "{0}",
                template: "#= series.name #: #= data.series.time #"
            }
```

I have all data which are at **series.time** not **one** which should be. Maybe someone know how to connect this array with tooltip so that print one correct value.